# Multiple streams in CEP Engine (Esper)

Tags: java, esper, complex-event-processing

I am new about esper engine and I am not sure about meaning of multiple streams. I want to create something like this:

```
 CepEnigine cep = new CepEngine();
 Controller.getInstance().setRuntime(cep.getRuntime());

 for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
     new EventGenerator().start();
```

Event generator class is defined like this:

```
public class EventGenerator extends Thread
{
    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while (true)
        {
             MyEvent e = new Event();
             Controller.getInstance().sendToCEP(e);
             Thread.sleep(500);
        }
    }
}
```

Controller is multithreading singleton that keeps epruntime to send events. In CepEngine class I have also EPL statement for listening to events. Is this good meaning of multiple event streams?

THX

Answer (score 0):

An event stream is "A time ordered sequence of events in time"

[Esper FAQs for Reference](http://esper.codehaus.org/tutorials/solution_patterns/solution_patterns.html#stream)

In the example you have given, there is one eventStream called MyEvent

A multiple Stream example would be Streams for Order and OrderBook . From Order events we can filter out the Order for book and create an orderBook event stream,

Check this test in the esper code base [TestFilterPropertySimple](http://svn.codehaus.org/esper/esper/trunk/esper/src/test/java/com/espertech/esper/regression/view/TestFilterPropertySimple.java)